# Straight and non-straight parent-child connections in tikz-qtree

Tags: trees, tikz-qtree

I want to acheive something of this sort, (without the bounding boxes):

[image: Binomial tree diagram]

Here, the first child has a straight line from the parent, and the following ones are diagonal.

What tikzset settings will allow that, or how would I go about acheiving this, and where can I learn more about it for the future?

currently I have:

```
\tikzset{every tree node/.style={minimum width=2em,draw,circle},
         blank/.style={draw=none},
         edge from parent/.style=
         {draw, edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode) -- (\tikzchildnode)}},
         level distance=1.5cm}
```

which I got from a post on tex.sx without knowing too much about how it works.

Comment: If you're willing to use a different tree-package, you could take a look at `forest`. There is a similar example on page 6 of [the manual](http://texdoc.net/pkg/forest).

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Would be open to try.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. forest looks way better for my use case. Alot of thanks for mentioning it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the *forest* package, you can define a style, which we will call here *B*, and then apply it to every tree:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{forest}

\forestset{
    B/.style={for tree={calign=last, circle,draw}}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
B
[9 
  [6
    [4
      [3]
    ]
    [2]
  ]
  [5
    [1]
  ]
  [7]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: Rendered binomal tree]

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative via `tikz` tree. Here an `event` style is defined for each node to have a circle shape.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
 [event/.style={circle,thick,draw,text width=0.6cm, text centered,font=\sffamily,anchor=north},
 edge from parent/.style={very thick,draw=black!70},
 ]
 \node (g) [event] {} 
       child {node[event,below= 1cm of g] (e3) {}}
       child {node[event,left=1cm of e3] (e2) {} 
                child {node[event, below=1cm of e2] (e21) {}    
                      }
             }           
       child {node[event,left=1cm of e2] (e1){}
                child {node[event,below= 1cm of e1] (e11) {} 
                      }
                child {node[event,left=1cm of e11]  (e12) {}
                          child[event]{node[event]{}}
                      }
             };  
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```